# A methods modifying a database is making a method to remove a row from the database not function

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm building an election database for university using flask and html for the ui. I have a page listing my candidates and their parties with a field to change the party and a button that should remove the candidate altogether. When I click the remove button, it changes the party to "None".

The thing is, when I completely remove the functionality to change the party - button and method both - the button removes the row from the database as intended.

Here are the relevant methods:

```
@app.route("/votes/<candidate_id>/", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def candidate_set_party(candidate_id):

    p = Candidate.query.get(candidate_id)
    p.party = request.form.get("party")
    db.session().commit()

    return redirect(url_for("votes_index"))
```

```
@app.route("/votes/<candidateid>/", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def candidate_remove(candidateid):
    #c = Candidate.query.get(candidate_id)


    print("debug")
    db.session().query(Candidate).filter(Candidate.id == candidateid).delete()
    #db.session().delete(c)
    #votes.delete().where(votes.Candidate.id==candidate_id)
    db.session().commit()

    #d = addresses_table.delete(Candidate.query.get(id))
    #d.execute()

    return redirect(url_for("votes_index"))
```

Here's the html page:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Party</th>
    </tr>
    {% for candidate in votes %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ candidate.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ candidate.party }}</td>
      <td>
          <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('candidate_set_party', candidate_id=candidate.id) }}">
            <input type="text" name="party"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Set party"/>
          </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('candidate_remove', candidateid=candidate.id) }}">
          <input type="submit" value="Remove candidate"/>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('cast_vote', candidate_id=candidate.id) }}">
          <input type="submit" value="Vote"/>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's the repo in case I missed something: https://github.com/skajanti/Aanestys

When I have the functionality to change party in my program, candidate_remove is not called at all (hence the print("debug")). Instead it somehow changes the party to "None" (maybe flask representation of a null input?).

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like both your candidate_remove and candidate_set_party functions are registered to the same routes and methods.

They need to have unique routes. I'll provide an example, in case I'm not being clear.

```py
@app.route("/set-party/<candidate_id>/", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def candidate_set_party(candidate_id):
    p = Candidate.query.get(candidate_id)
    p.party = request.form.get("party")
    db.session().commit()
    return redirect(url_for("votes_index"))

@app.route("/remove-candidate/<candidateid>/", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def candidate_remove(candidateid):
    db.session().query(Candidate).filter(Candidate.id == candidateid).delete()
    db.session().commit()
    return redirect(url_for("votes_index"))
```

The HTML can remain the same.